# angular 6 hide all div if another div is shown clicked (only one can be shown)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have list of supervisors that have subordinates you can view when you click on the `caret` class.

Supervisor with subordinates can be viewed once per click of the caret.

**HTML**

```
<div id="detailed" *ngFor="let summary of summaries; let i = index">
    <div class="list-group">
        <div class="list-group-item" style="position: relative;">
            <div class="caret" *ngIf="summary.isSupervisor" style="position: absolute; left: 15px; cursor: pointer;" (click)="openSubordinateInfo(i, summary)">
                 <i class="zmdi" [ngClass]="{'zmdi-caret-down': detailedInfo[i], 'zmdi-caret-right': !detailedInfo[i]}" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- list of Supervisors -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="detailedInfo[i] == true">
            <!-- list of Subordinates -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

** TS **

```
detailedInfo = [];

openSubordinateInfo(i, summary) {

    if(this.detailedInfo[i]) {
      this.detailedInfo[i] = false;
    } else {
      this.detailedInfo[i] = true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// in .ts
// Add this line, after defining summaries array, also make sure to update detailedInfo array every time length of summaries array changes.
detailedInfo = new Array(this.summaries.length).fill(false);

// Add this function anywhere after ngOnInit();
openSubordinateInfo(i, summary) {
    this.detailedInfo[i] = !this.detailedInfo[i];
}
```

Comment: Or in short you could just do `detailedInfo.fill(false)`

Comment: @nash11 In that case, how will it decide, how much length of **detailedInfo** array will be? `detailedInfo.fill(false)` will work, if detailedInfo array is initialised with some length or with some elements before.

Comment: Thanks for your response. unfortunately it throws this error on my console. `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: @Terence make sure, you paste this code bellow defining **summaries** array, which you are using in HTML template.

Comment: It's not working properly on my end. i can still open multiple subordinates

Comment: Can you show us code for this component only? (.ts and .html both) On **codesandbox** or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198659/discussion-between-terence-and-jayraj).

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**

```
<div id="detailed" *ngFor="let summary of summaries; let i = index">
    <div class="list-group">
        <div class="list-group-item" style="position: relative;">
            <div class="caret" *ngIf="summary.isSupervisor" style="position: absolute; left: 15px; cursor: pointer;" (click)="openSubordinateInfo(i, summary)">
                 <i class="zmdi" [ngClass]="{'zmdi-caret-down': detailedInfo===i, 'zmdi-caret-right': detailedInfo!==i}" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- list of Supervisors -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="detailedInfo===i">
            <!-- list of Subordinates -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

** TS **

```
detailedInfo: number | null = null;

openSubordinateInfo(i, summary) {

    if(this.detailedInfo === i) {
      this.detailedInfo = null;
    } else {
      this.detailedInfo === i;
    }

}
```